# Executing roles locally and remotely in Ansible/AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

I have written two roles with Ansible. The first role (i.e. provision) is executed locally on an instance that has the required IAMs to provision EC2 instances (see below):

```
- name: Provison "{{ count }}" ec2 instances in "{{ region }}"
  ec2:
     key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
     instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
     image: "{{ image }}"
 ...
     exact_count: "{{ count }}"
     count_tag: "{{ count_tag }}"
     instance_tags:
 ...
  register: ec2
```

I then add the private IP address to hosts.

```
- name: Add the newly created EC2 instances to the local host file
  local_action: lineinfile
                dest="./hosts"
                regexp={{ item.private_ip }}
                insertafter="[sit]" line={{ item.private_ip }}
  with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```

I wait for SSH to be available.

```
- name: Wait for SSH process to be available on "{{ sit }}"
  wait_for:
    host: "{{ item.private_ip }}"
    port: 22
    delay: 60
    timeout: 320
    state: started
  with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```

The second role (i.e. setupEnv) sets up environmental variables on the 'sit' hosts such as users/group directories. I attempt to run the roles sequentially (see below `main.yml` playbook):

```
- hosts: local
  roles:
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  user: svc_ansible_lab
  roles:
  - provision

- hosts: sit
  roles:
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: true
  user: ec2-user
  roles:
  - setupEnv
```

However, only the first role gets executed on local host. Ansible waits until SSH is available on the provisioned instances and then the process finishes without attmpting role setupEnv.

***Is there a way I can make sure the second role is executed on the `sit` hosts after the SSH is available?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inventory file will not be automatically re-sourced in between the plays.

Instead of modifying the inventory file, use [`add_host` module and in-memory inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/add_host_module.html).

```
- name: Add the newly created EC2 instances to the in-memory inventory
  add_host:
    hostname: "{{ item.private_ip }}"
    groups: sit
  with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```

---

Alternatively you might use the [`meta` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/meta_module.html) with `refresh_inventory` parameter to force Ansible to re-read the inventory file:

```
- meta: refresh_inventory
```

Comment: ah! thanks.  I figured it was memory related since I ran the script twice and the first setup instances were setup with the parameters I gave them. But I didn't know how to add the hosts in memory. That said the add_host does not change my inventory on the disk. I should still use *lineinfile* to midify my hosts file?